is signal asReadonly automatically overwrites original source?
How does signal asReadonly() work?
private _users = signal<User[]>([]);
users = this._users.asReadonly();

addUser(newUser: User): void {
   mutating current value
   this._users.mutate(users => users.push(newUser));
}

Does it automatically overwrittes _users?what is the sense of it?

Property mutate does not exist on this._users.

asReadOnly returns a WritableSignal as a readonly Signal. Which means you can't update the value of the signal with .set or .update

The signal generally has a set method with which, we can update the signal and propogate the changes.
When we use asReadOnly, we can covert a writable signal to a readOnly signal.
The readOnly signal, will not have the methods set and update, which can be used to modify the signal state directly.

These signals are useful when you want to share the signal to other components but ensure that the components that use these signals, do not have access to modify them without modifying the source signal, that was used to create the readonly signal.

Hence it is read only.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    {{users() | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  private _users = signal<any[]>([]);
  users = this._users.asReadonly();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._users.set([{ test: 'hello' }]); // <- valid
    this._users.update((state: any) => [...state, { asdf: 'hello' }]); // <- valid
    // invalid set is not accessible in read only signal, so the signal blocks updates.
    // this.users.set; // <- does not exist
    // this.users.update; // <- does not exist
  }
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  signal,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
        {{_users() | json}}
      `,
})
export class App {
  private _users = signal<any[]>([]);
  users = this._users.asReadonly();

  addUser(newUser: any): void {
    this._users.set([{ test: 'hello' }]); // <- valid
    this._users.update((state: any) => [...state, { asdf: 'hello' }]); // <- valid
    // invalid set is not accessible in read only signal, so the signal blocks updates.
    // this.users.set; // <- does not exist
    // this.users.update; // <- does not exist
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

We can still modify the signal inner values containing an complex object or an array of objects, but these do not count as proper signal updates, since the memory reference of the object or array has to be updated using object destructuring or array spread operator to be counted as an update.
